# Connecting to MySQL DB and retrieving information

Tags: php, mysql

This is the first time I am using MySQL in a website and I need some help getting all setup. I have all my tables created and primary keys set, however I am a little lost on how to connect to the database and retrieve information. I added 1  sample album with albumdID 1 and 3 sample photos. Right now though I am not even sure if I am connecting to the database. I setup my config.php file also. I will post my code below, all this code is from my Index.php file. Thank you

```
       <?php
// create the connection  (host, username, pw, dbname)
// and give feedback if that fails
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'tmh233sp14', 'ECHOB8Se', 'info230_SP14_tmh233sp14');

// check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   printf('Connect failed: %s\n', mysqli_connect_error());
   exit();
}


// construct the query 
$albumID =1;
$sql = "SELECT Photos.photoID FROM Photos";
var_dump($sql);

// execute the query 
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

// get the result set
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

// iterate over result array to display stuff
var_dump($result); // for debugging use var_dump, to see whats inside

// close the connection
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not mix mysql_* and mysqli_* functions. My advice: stick to mysqli_*

This example should get you going:

```
<?php
// create the connection  (host, username, pw, dbname)
// and give feedback if that fails
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'tmh233sp14', 'password', 'info230_SP14_sjs334sp14');

// check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
   exit();
}

// construct the query 
$albumId =1
$sql = "SELECT Photos.photoID, Photos.name FROM photos 
        LEFT JOIN photoInAlbum ON (photoInAlbum.photoID = Photos.photoID) 
        WHERE albumID = $albumID";

// execute the query     
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

// get the result set
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

// iterate over result array to display stuff
var_dump($result); // for debugging use var_dump, to see whats inside

// close the connection
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: my issue is I am not sure where to put that. Do I enclose it in PHP tags in the index.php file? Anywhere specific, header, body etc?

Comment: Yes, enclose it in PHP tags and replace your section starting with mysql_connect. Later you might decide, to put the database stuff into a database.php file and include that file, with include('database.php'); to keep the index file clean. But to get started, just place it right at the spot where you need it.

Comment: ok so after I replace what I have, should it retrieve the 1 sample album and 3 sample photos? or how would I go about doing that part

Comment: if the query is correct the var_dump($result); should show you the database result set. does it output your db data?

Comment: It does not load, I posted my code above, must be something wrong with the php, if I take it out the sql it loads, but with it, it wont load

Comment: yes, thats because of the die() statement. Whats the full error message? "Some error occurred during connection" ....

Comment: yea Some error occurred during connection is the full error

Comment: mysqli_error() is not displayed then. use ini_set('display_errors', '1'); directly after opening PHP tag.

Comment: This is the error I am getting, must be a more detailed one Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/info230/SP14/users/tmh233sp14/www/P3/index.php on line 40
NULL

Comment: Please look for failure conditions. Check what each function returns and that it is of the expected type. Here: the mysqli_query() returned "false" (boolean). The following function mysqli_fetch_array() can't work with that. But that's not the source of the error :) Check the return value of mysqli_connect. var_dump($con); Fix the connection! Check the credentials, check db running, port not blocked, hostname correct..

Comment: Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (42000/1044): Access denied for user 'tmh233sp14'@'localhost' to database 'info230_SP14_tmhsp14' in /home/info230/SP14/users/tmh233sp14/www/P3/index.php on line 27
Connect failed: Access denied for user 'tmh233sp14'@'localhost' to database 'info230_SP14_tmhsp14' that is the error I get now, I know all my login stuff is correct

Comment: Triple-check for typos :) Finally: use a tool like Adminer (http://www.adminer.org/de/#download) to check your database connection. Just download the PHP file, drop it where your index.php is and open the file in your browser - try to access db with this tool. db name correct "info230_SP14_tmhsp14" or "info230_SP14_tmh233sp14"?

Comment: Hmm I will check it out and make sure all my settings are right again. Thanks very much for the help, hopefully figure this out

Comment: well I fixed the connection error, however I still get this error, any idea how to fix it? Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/info230/SP14/users/tmh233sp14/www/P3/index.php on line 46
NULL

Comment: do i even have an array to fetch?

Comment: Congrats, for solving the connection problem. Next step: mysqli_query() returns false on failure. Check your query! Maybe start with something simple $result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM photos"); var_dump($result);. Test your query in Adminer :)

Comment: ok so I went through line by line, and these 2 lines are causing the error. // get the result set
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

// iterate over result array to display stuff
var_dump($result); // for debugging use var_dump, to see whats inside
do I even have an array for $result to get though?

Comment: What does var_dump($query); give?

Comment: bool(false) is what appears

Comment: Ok, that means mysqli_query is not working correctly, right? Two parameters to this function: We know that $con is the connection, which is successfully made. Check again: var_dump($con). Next step: checkl that the query to your db is correct: that's the $sql statement. For testing, just change it to a simple query: $sql = "SELECT * FROM photos";

Comment: Does this look ok for in my php tags to execute? Just a simple one. I updated it in OP

Comment: With using that in the OP, I get "string(33) "SELECT Photos.photoID FROM Photos" array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" ["photoID"]=> string(1) "1" }
"

Comment: I just want to test a simple query at first, but in the end all I want to do is display the album or/and pictures from the database. Would communicating be easier through email for you?

Comment: Nice, you will get there. Sry, no email, just Stackoverflow. - At this point you connected, made a simple query and got a result set. Now you can use echo 'Image'.$result['photoID']; , ok? Next step: fix your original query, so that you get again array as response. When you have that: iterate/foreach over it and output your data.